# Retrieving Array data stored in plist File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

How can we retrieve the array data stored in plist file.

The plist file and source code is as shown below,

```
------------------------plist File-------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>abcxxx</string>
    <key>Phones</key>
    <array/>
    <key>item1</key>
    <string>121327777</string>
    <key>item2</key>
    <string>333333333</string>
</dict>
</plist>
---------------------------------------------------------



  -(id) init
{


    NSString *errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    phoneNumbers =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testfile" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];

    NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                          propertyListFromData:plistXML
                                          mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                          format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];

    if(!temp){
        NSLog(errorDesc);
        [errorDesc release];
    }
    self.personName = [temp objectForKey:@"Name"];
    self.phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"Phones"]];
    NSLog(@"Label executed %@",[phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:0]);

    UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-180, 100, 100, 20)];
    name.text = [phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:1];
    [self addChild:name];
    NSLog(@"Label executed %@",name);
```

Comment: You don't say what the actual problem is. What are the symptons?

Answer (score 1):

Your plist XML looks a little suspicious.  The `<array/>` tag you have is just a standalone tag, which I'm not sure will do anything useful.

Maybe change the plist to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>abcxxx</string>
    <key>Phones</key>
    <array>
        <string>121327777</string>
        <string>333333333</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm not sure whether this will help w/ your code.  Have you read through this documentation?

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is call NSDictionary's initWithContentsOfFile: method. For example

```
NSDictionary *temp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
self.personName = [temp objectForKey:@"Name"];
self.phoneNumbers = [[temp objectForKey:@"Phones"] mutableCopy];
```

However, as mentioned above, your plist does look a little suspicious, try changing it to the one Andy White provided as well.

Regards,

Kyle

Comment: That doesn't make all the containers and leaves mutable though, whereas the NSPropertyListSerialization technique does.

Answer (score 0):

The frame of the UITextField is also weird (depending on self's frame) `CGRectMake(-180, 100, 100, 20)` is probably offscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your simply not being able to read the plist, just check your plist structure,

```
 NSString *StringsFromPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSString *itemPositionPlistLocation = [StringsFromPList stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Words.plist"];
 _myDictionary= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:itemPositionPlistLocation];
NSArray * items = [_myDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"];


<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <string>Happy</string>
        <string>Rain</string>
    </array>
```

Hope it helps :)